# I have a 20 in frame that I can not complete bc I have no cups for my forks. It's a Threadless frame and I don't know what brand cups to buy frame

Tags: fork

What kind of cups do I need to buy and can I get a fork and cup set for this bike I have pictures of the frame I am trying to send

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please provide make/model information for your forks, especially if you can't post photos.

Answer (score 3):

From the title of your post you are looking for a threadless headset so you need to know what specification the headtube is. The size of the frame isn’t relevant here.

It can be 1-1/8 inch straight or 1-1/8 inch to 1-1/2 inch tapered. It should be obvious which one you have.

Once you know which one you have you can purchase a headset. Like all parts cheap isn’t great but super expensive won’t give you any major extra value either.

A threadless headset is an interference fit which means you need to press them in place. It’s technically possible to do it with a block of wood and a mallet but it’s very easy to go wrong that way.

It would be better to use a bike store to do the job as a headset press is something the average home mechanic will use a small number of times in their life.

Homemade headset presses can be made with threaded rod, nuts, washers and metal plate. The internet knows how.